# Program not returning float and giving different results depending on compiler used?

Tags: c, loops, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void averageGuess(int);
int main()
{
    int i, userInput, compGuess, totalGuess, loopGuess = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 99: \n");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        loopGuess = 0;
        do
        {
            compGuess = (rand() % 100);
            loopGuess++;
        } while(compGuess != userInput);

        totalGuess += loopGuess;
    }
    averageGuess(totalGuess);
    return 0;
}//end main

void averageGuess(int totalGuess)
{
    float average;
    average = totalGuess / 50;
    printf("The program took an average of %lf random number generations to match the target number over the 50 experiments.", average);
}//end function
```

The goal is for the program to print out a float but **all I get is integers**. I've compiled it in Codeblocks and an Online C compiler but the latter is giving me **negative numbers** while Codeblocks **doesn't return a float**.

Can't tell if it is an issue with my code or compiler.

Comment: Well, all your variables are of type `int`; why would you expect the program to print a `float` then?

Comment: totalGuess is an int, 50 is an int so the division is done as an int.  Try using 50.0 instead, or casting totalGuess to float.

Comment: @Starch Wars This expression   totalGuess / 50 evaluates as an integer expression. Instead write totalGuess / 50.0f;

Comment: @Starch Wars Also the enclosed loops do not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It was the instructions for the assignment but thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division

Comment: about the difference between compilers: `totalGuess` isn't initalized. That explains a lot. The rest is in the duplicate link.

Comment: `userInput, compGuess, totalGuess, loopGuess = 0;` only sets `loopGuess` to 0.

Comment: reopened, and answered :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with the code here:

```
    average = totalGuess / 50;
```

The '/' operator sees two integers it has to divide and hence returns an integer. If you need the result to be a float use 50.0 instead of 50

Comment: And how this operation can give the negative number as it was asked by OP?

Comment: Because totalGuess is not initializated to 0 and can contain a negative number at beginning. See Jean-François Fabre comment.

Answer (score 0):

> I've compiled it in Codeblocks and an Online C compiler but the latter is giving me negative numbers

this line:

```
int i, userInput, compGuess, totalGuess, loopGuess = 0;
```

is *not* setting all variables to `0`, just `loopGuess`. So `totalGuess` isn't initialized, which explains
the difference in behaviour (and wrong result, initial value of `totalGuess` is random, can be negative) between different compilers. Fix:

```
int i, userInput, compGuess, totalGuess = 0, loopGuess = 0;
```

> The goal is for the program to print out a float but all I get is integers

Then use *floating point division*, not *integer division*

```
float average;
average = totalGuess / 50.0;
```

gcc doesn't warn about the uninitialized variable (bad!) but clang does (and even suggests the right fix, wow!):

```
S:\>gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
(no warnings!!)
S:\>clang -Wall -Wextra test.c

test.c:23:9: warning: variable 'totalGuess' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
        totalGuess += loopGuess;
        ^~~~~~~~~~
test.c:8:44: note: initialize the variable 'totalGuess' to silence this warning
    int i, userInput, compGuess, totalGuess, loopGuess = 0;
                                           ^
                                            = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code:

a) `totalGuess` is divided by integer so the result is rounded to `int` value

`average =  totalGuess / 50;`

b) negative numbers comes from the fact that 
`totalGuess` variable is not initialized so it can be any number (like big negative to start with).

Corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void averageGuess(int totalGuess)
{
    float average;
    average =  totalGuess / 50.0;
    printf("The program took an average of %.2f random number generations to match the target number over the 50 experiments.", average);
}

int main()
{
    int i, userInput, compGuess;
    int totalGuess = 0;
    double loopGuess = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 99: \n");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        loopGuess = 0;
        do
        {
            compGuess = (rand() % 100);
            loopGuess++;

        } while(compGuess != userInput);

        totalGuess += loopGuess;
    }

    averageGuess(totalGuess);
    return 0;
}//end main
```